# SQL Server XML DataType butchers my CDATA Section

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I have a table with one column with `XML` datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(200),
  ExtraInfo XML
)
```

I must use the XML data type for ExtraInfo column, and I have the following INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES 
(1, 'John Doe', 
CONVERT(XML, '<root><section><![CDATA[Some weird content with weird characters (*&#^@$]]></section></root>'))
```

After the above statement is executed, I end up with the following in the ExtraInfo column.

```
<root>
  <section>Some weird content with weird characters (*&amp;#^@$</section>
</root>
```

How do I keep my `CDATA` section intact?

I have already checked the [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189476/sql-server-xml-data-with-cdata-block), that is not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement needs to use **parenthesis** (`CREATE TABLE (......)`) - not curly braces ( `{ ... }`) for it to be valid T-SQL code ...

Comment: this is expected behavior - some characters are escaped due to xml guidelines

Comment: to further elaborate - change the xml data type to string and perform the same insert and youll see what i mean.

Comment: @DougCoats Are these guidelines with this CDATA escaping clause stipulated somewhere? I looked up MSDN and found nothing.

Comment: You can't tune the behavior of SQL Server's XML encoding in this regard. If you need this, the only thing you can do is store the data as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` -- but any operation on it with the XML methods will result in the CDATA being recoded again. Do note that the markup you get here is *equivalent* (if you query for the contents of `section` using `.value`, you will get the correct data back) even if it's not *identical*.

Comment: @fahadash https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/xml-escaped-chars.html

Comment: @DougCoats Thank you for linking me to the page of XML Escaped Characters. I was actually looking for something from Microsoft stating that the XML data type does not support CDATA sections.

Answer (score 1):

> I was actually looking for something from Microsoft stating that the
> XML data type does not support CDATA sections.

Here it is: [How to get [CDATA] with FOR XML PATH?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e22efff3-192e-468e-b173-ced52ada857f/how-to-get-cdata-with-for-xml-path?forum=sqlxml)

Quote from Michael Rys who was responsible for most of the XML stuff in SQL Server at Microsoft:

> The XML datatype does not preserve CDATA sections... it is part of the
> W3C XQuery recommendation that it does not preserve CDATA section.