# SQL Server 2019 FOR XML nested nodes preserving CDATA

Tags: sql-server, cdata, for-xml-path, for-xml-explicit

I have to build this payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shipment>
    <software>
        <application>MYRTL</application>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </software>
    <security>
        <customer>X00000</customer>
        <user>X00000</user>
        <password>password1</password>
        <langid>IT</langid>
    </security>
    <consignment action="I" cashondeliver="N" international="N" insurance="N">
        <labelType>T</labelType>
        <senderAccId>200200</senderAccId>
        <consignmenttype>T</consignmenttype>
        <actualweight>00008000</actualweight>
        <actualvolume>0000018</actualvolume>
        <totalpackages>2</totalpackages>
        <packagetype>C</packagetype>
        <division>D</division>
        <product>N</product>
        <insurancevalue>0000000000000</insurancevalue>
        <insurancecurrency>EUR</insurancecurrency>
        <reference><![CDATA[22X000223]]></reference>
        <collectiondate>20220818</collectiondate>
        <termsofpayment>S</termsofpayment>
        <systemcode>RL</systemcode>
        <systemversion>1.0</systemversion>
        <codfvalue>0000000000000</codfvalue>
        <codfcurrency>EUR</codfcurrency>
        <goodsdesc><![CDATA[Bread, Butter & Puré]]></goodsdesc>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <addressType>S</addressType>
                <vatno>123456789123</vatno>
                <addrline1><![CDATA[Via Mondovì, n° 23]]></addrline1>
                <postcode><![CDATA[20125]]></postcode>
                <phone1><![CDATA[345]]></phone1>
                <phone2><![CDATA[3456345]]></phone2>
                <name><![CDATA[Jack & Joe srl]]></name>
                <country><![CDATA[IT]]></country>
                <town><![CDATA[Arquà Polesine]]></town>
                <province><![CDATA[RO]]></province>
                <email><![CDATA[mail@jack_and_joe.it]]></email>
            </address>
            <address>
                <addressType>C</addressType>
                <addrline1><![CDATA[12° Reggimento Granatieri, 14]]></addrline1>
                <postcode><![CDATA[00195]]></postcode>
                <phone1><![CDATA[321]]></phone1>
                <phone2><![CDATA[3214321]]></phone2>
                <name><![CDATA[Giosuè Rossë]]></name>
                <country><![CDATA[IT]]></country>
                <town><![CDATA[Gambolo']]></town>
                <province><![CDATA[TV]]></province>
                <email><![CDATA[mario@rossi.it]]></email>
            </address>
            <address>
                <addressType>R</addressType>
                <addrline1><![CDATA[Hauptstraße 13]]></addrline1>
                <postcode><![CDATA[34100]]></postcode>
                <phone1><![CDATA[333]]></phone1>
                <phone2><![CDATA[333444555]]></phone2>
                <name><![CDATA[Noè Giassù]]></name>
                <country><![CDATA[IT]]></country>
                <town><![CDATA[Völs am Schlern]]></town>
                <province><![CDATA[BZ]]></province>
                <email><![CDATA[mail@noe.it]]></email>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <collectiontrg>
            <priopntime>0900</priopntime>
            <priclotime>1200</priclotime>
            <secopntime>1400</secopntime>
            <secclotime>1800</secclotime>
            <availabilitytime>1600</availabilitytime>
            <pickupdate>18.08.2022</pickupdate>
            <pickuptime>1600</pickuptime>
            <pickupdays>1</pickupdays>
            <pickupinstr><![CDATA[Test Shipment ===> DO NOT COLLECT <===]]></pickupinstr>
        </collectiontrg>
        <dimensions itemaction="I">
            <itemsequenceno>1</itemsequenceno>
            <itemtype>C</itemtype>
            <itemreference><![CDATA[22X0002223_1]]></itemreference>
            <volume>0000009</volume>
            <weight>00003000</weight>
            <length>030000</length>
            <heigh>010000</heigh>
            <width>030000</width>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </dimensions>
        <dimensions itemaction="I">
            <itemsequenceno>2</itemsequenceno>
            <itemtype>C</itemtype>
            <itemreference><![CDATA[22X0002223_2]]></itemreference>
            <volume>0000009</volume>
            <weight>00005000</weight>
            <length>030000</length>
            <heigh>010000</heigh>
            <width>030000</width>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </dimensions>
    </consignment>
</shipment>
```

I had the bad idea to use T-SQL since all data are in SQL Server DB

I thought it was quite easy, and actually, it was, since was just required to nest some `FOR XML PATH, TYPE` subqueries.

Problems arose when considered that some fields could contain not standard charachters, therefore was better to use some CDATA fields.

I faced several problems since it appears that the only way to preserve CDATA is using `FOR XML EXPLICIT` that seems to be deprecated.
However it was very difficult to find documentation.

Fortunately I found this [post](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=160655) that helped me to make the reverse path:

Therefore I built a `sproc` with XML Explicit format:

```
SELECT  1 AS Tag,
        NULL AS Parent,

        'MYRTL' AS 'software!1!application!element',
        '1.0'   AS 'software!1!version!element',
       
        NULL AS 'security!2!customer!element',
        ...
        NULL AS 'security!2!langid!element',

        NULL AS 'consignment!3!action',
        ...
        NULL AS 'consignment!3!goodsdesc!CDATA',

        NULL AS 'addresses!4!address',

        NULL AS 'address!5!addressType!element',
        ...
        NULL AS 'address!5!town!CDATA',
       
        ...

        NULL  AS 'collectiontrg!9!priopntime!element',
        ...
        NULL  AS 'collectiontrg!9!pickupdate!element',



UNION ALL
SELECT  2 AS Tag,
        NULL AS Parent,
        ...
UNION ALL
SELECT  3 AS Tag,
        NULL AS Parent,
        ...
UNION ALL
SELECT  9 AS Tag,
        3 AS Parent,
        ...

FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('shipment')
```

It seems to be working well... although I think there has to be a better way to build it.

Now I have a further issue that I do not know how to solve, or better, I could solve it using a dynamic query, but I would avoid it:

New issue is that node `shipment.consignment.addresses.address` where `addressType=='C'`

has to be omitted if it contains the same values as `shipment.consignment.addresses.address` where `addressType=='S'`

furthermore the node `shipment.consignment.collectiontrg` has to appear only if the variable `pickupDate` is not null

Is there a way to avoid the dynamic query?

Is there a better way to build this query?
Thanks

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Do you have a table you are building this off? If so please include it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954507/sql-server-xml-datatype-butchers-my-cdata-section

Comment: SQL Server essentially doesn't support CDATA preservation except when using `FOR XML` without `TYPE`, so you are always going to have problems with it. As to your question: We cannot help you without sample data. Please include it as I asked.

Comment: @Charlieface Data are collected from more than 10 Tables so difficult to show here.
I added to the XML some pseudo real data: Most issues can arise from Addresses:
Address Fields are saved as nvarchar() since can contain typical italian accented characters `(àèéìòù sometimes rendered with an ' after the vowel: ù -> u')` but also French characters `(èéçëê)`, or german `(ä,ö,ü,ß)`, and since are used for shipping parcels, also greek and cyrillic characters could be included. Beside this, the Carrier (TNT) suggest to enclose addresses in `CDATA` Section

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with just using the values as they are, should work fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=320456011c3c8191654a7f9dcf26f5c4

Comment: @Charlieface for example... &: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f1b00bca7f34203747b8ac99c30c5c2

Beside this, although I send an utf-8 encoded xml, TNT answers with an  ISO-8859-1 encoded XML: I do not know if this can affect how the payload is managed, but point is that TNT suggests (but it means 'requires') to use CDATA section

Comment: It's *supposed* to be encoded `&amp;` that's how you escape `&` in XML. The reason SQL Server does not preserve CDATA is because it is semantically equivalent. The fact TNT cannot handle perfectly conformant UTF-8 or UTF-16 XML, and instead mangles it into 8859 means *they* are not conformant. I suggest you use a procedural language such as Python or C# to produce their non-conformant so-called XML format. Have you tried concatenating `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>` to the start of the XML?

Comment: yes, sproc starts with 

`select (CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',(
select * from (

SELECT 1 AS Tag,
  NULL AS Parent,

  'MYRTL' AS "software!1!application!element",
  '1.0'   AS "software!1!version!element",
...`

I was willing to use TSQL because I already use it for other Carriers that requires JSON payload, in way to use the same method for all carriers.

I think I will remove the 2 nodes via script after importing and parsing the SQL Server output: will be few lines of code. Thanks a lot.